# Can not call a user defined function with CHAR parameter on DB2 for i

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, parameters, create-function

I create a function in DB2 (Version 6.01) this way:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myschema.test_c_c(param CHAR(1)) RETURNS CHAR(1) RETURN param;
```

and get a succses message and "System i Navigator" show me that function under myschema. But when I try to call this function this way:

```
SELECT myschema.test_c_c('X') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

I get following message:

```
[SQL0204] TEST_C_C der Art *N in myschema nicht gefunden. 
[SQL State=42704, DB Errorcode=-204]
```

"nicht gefunden" equals to "not found".

**Explanation of error code -204** (part of it, [full error code Description here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes/src/tpc/n204.htm))

"The object identified by name is not defined in the DB2® subsystem."

And at last, with INT parameter all works fine:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myschema.test_i_ri(param INT) RETURNS INT RETURN param;
SELECT myschema.test_i_ri(4711) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
CREATE FUNCTION myschema.test_ii_ri(param1 INT, param2 INT) RETURNS INT RETURN param1 +param2;
SELECT myschema.test_ii_ri(800, 15) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Where I miss the point?

I execute all statmentens with [SQL Workbench/J](http://www.sql-workbench.net/) (which I find very usefull)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of try error and research I ask the question and then 30 minutes later I found the answere by myself.

The problem is the resolution of overloaded functions in DB2. When calling

```
SELECT myschema.test_c_c('X') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

this way, DB2 interpret 'X' as VARCHAR but I have no version of test_c_c with VARCHAR params. What work is

```
SELECT CESDTA.TEST_C_C(CAST('X' AS CHAR(1))) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Or declare a VARCHAR function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION cesdta.test_v_v(param VARCHAR(1)) RETURNS VARCHAR(1000) RETURN param;
SELECT cesdta.test_v_v('X') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Comment: Personally, if I'd already declared a 'canonical' version (ie, the `CHAR`-accepting one), I'd just have the other versions to casts/conversions, and funnel into the original.  However, good that you've found it - go ahead and accept your own answer when you're able.